# Does gradle support comma in version to specify several ranges?

Tags: gradle, versioning

Does Gradle support comma in version to specify several ranges?

Like:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'org.webjars.npm:minimatch:2.+,3.+'
}
```

or:

```
  compile 'org.webjars.npm:minimatch:[2,3),[3,4)'
```

[It is allowed in Maven](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution#DependencyMediationandConflictResolution-DependencyVersionRanges):

> (,1.0],[1.2,)
>   x <= 1.0 or x >= 1.2. Multiple sets are comma-separated
>
> (,1.1),(1.1,)
>   This excludes 1.1 if it is known not to work in combination with this library

For:

```
dependencies {
    compile(group: 'org.webjars.npm', name: 'glob', version: '5.0.15') {
}
```

it failed as:

```
Execution failed for task ':dump'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtime'.
  > Could not find org.webjars.npm:minimatch:[2,3),[3,4).
  Searched in the following locations:
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/npm/minimatch/[2,3),[3,4)/minimatch-[2,3),[3,4).pom
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/webjars/npm/minimatch/[2,3),[3,4)/minimatch-[2,3),[3,4).jar
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webjars/npm/minimatch/[2,3),[3,4)/minimatch-[2,3),[3,4).pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/webjars/npm/minimatch/[2,3),[3,4)/minimatch-[2,3),[3,4).jar
 Required by:
     project : > org.webjars.npm:glob:5.0.15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Gradle yet supports such multiple version ranges, but single ranges. You should search in the issue tracker whether this is reported already and open a new issue if it is not, so it can get fixed eventually.

To solve the issue, you can either use a newer version of that library, in the latest version it doesn't use multiple ranges, but only single ranges.
Alternatively you can either exclude the transitive dependency and include a version yourself or write a dependency resolution rule that selects a specific version for that range.

**One** of these should help I'd say if you still want to use the aged version of `glob`.

```
dependencies {
    compile(group: 'org.webjars.npm', name: 'glob', version: '5.0.15') {
        exclude group: 'org.webjars.npm', module: 'minimatch'
    }
    runtime 'org.webjars.npm:minimatch:3.+'
}
```

---

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module("org.webjars.npm:minimatch") with module("org.webjars.npm:minimatch:3.0.4") 
    }
}
```

---

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if ((it.requested.group == 'org.webjars.npm') && (it.requested.name == 'minimatch')) {
            it.useTarget group: it.requested.group, name: it.requested.name, version: '3.0.4'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3869 - *Transitive dependency for list of version ranges breaks build*

Answer (score 0):

Gradle uses Ivy to resolve dependencies:

```
at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:105)
```

and Ivy doesn't support version list, at least I can't find examples in docs:

- http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/dependency.html
- http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/version-matchers.html

I fixed problem as usual:

```
dependencies {
    compile(group: 'org.webjars.npm', name: 'glob', version: '5.0.15') {
        exclude module: 'minimatch'
    }
    compile 'org.webjars.npm:minimatch:3.0.4'
}
```

Comment: Gradle does **not** use Ivy for dependency resolution. It supports some of the Ivy syntax and it supports Ivy repositories, but it has a complete own dependency resolution mechanism. It is correct that I think, that Gradle does not currently support multiple ranges and the suggested resolution is one way to solve it, but the Ivy documentation is not appropriate here and the statement that Ivy is used for dependency resolution is plainly wrong. :-)